# Apache PIG - Sampling grouped data in foreach using a percentage value

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have country-region data in a pig relation which I am trying to sample based on number of countries in each region. I want to filter 10% of the countries from each region. I am trying to use SAMPLE within FOREACH for this , but looks like SAMPLE is not supported within FOREACH.

```
COUNTRY_FULL = LOAD 'COUNTRY_REGION' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

COUNTRIES = FILTER COUNTRY_FULL by partition_dt=='2016-09-04';

COUNTRIES_GROUPED_BY_REGION = GROUP COUNTRIES BY region_id;

SAMPLED_DATA = FOREACH COUNTRIES_GROUPED_BY_REGION {
    SAMPLED = SAMPLE COUNTRIES 0.1;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(SAMPLED);
};

DUMP SAMPLED_DATA;
```

Is there a way to achieve this percentage based sampling within a grouped relation in pig ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard trick here is to perform the desired operation (for example sample) before or after your foreach.

In this case I would say it should be possible to use the sample function somewhere before the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this out so not sure about the syntactical correctness, but what if we try something on the following lines. We basically sort inside the nested foreach on a random number and pick the top 10% of this data:

```
data = countries, RANDOM() as random;
orderedData = ORDER data BY random;
sampledData = LIMIT orderedData COUNT(data)/10;
GENERATE FLATTEN(sampledData);
```